# Add Description to product

Tags: product

Hi I am new to word press and am battling with WooCommerce, my description is not showing when I click the product. it takes me to a page that is not available as per below

http://mini-mee.co.za/minimee/?product=hsbk5132

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your *Permalink Settings* and setup *Post name* option.
Settings > Permalinks